# ExtractByMask ignoring my set workspace, saving to Default.gdb instead

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, extract-by-mask

I am calculating NDVI and then want to mask it with a vector file. I set my workspace a gdb and the NDVI raster calculator function saves to my gdb but the extract by mask saves to the Default.gdb.

Note: file path names changed for question posting

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\example\\example\\example\\example\\example\\example\\example.gdb" 
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#Local Variables
Band4 = "Band4"
Band5 = "Band5"
NDVI_raw = "NDVI_raw"
NDVI = "NDVI" #Masked NDVI
Neighbourhoods = "Neighbourhoods"

#Calculate NDVI
arcpy.gp.RasterCalculator_sa("(Float(\"Band5\") - Float(\"Band4\")) / (Float(\"Band5\") + Float(\"Band4\"))", NDVI_raw)

#Mask out NDVI
ExtractByMask_NDVI = ExtractByMask(NDVI_raw, Neighbourhoods)
```

Comment: Where is the code where you're writing the ExtractByMask_NDVI? You could skip that step by specifying arcpy.env.mask = Neighbourhoods assuming Neighbourhoods is in your workspace GDB then set arcpy.env.extent = Neighbourhoods and arcpy.env.cellsize = Band4 before running your calculation. I notice you've set variables for Band4 and Band5 but aren't using them, is this intentional?

Comment: @MichaelStimson I don't exactly know what you mean by where is the code? Are you saying I don't need the "ExtractByMask_NDVI =" in front of the ExtracByMask function?

Comment: You do but it's a raster object https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000051000000 not a file, you need to save it using ExtractByMask_NDVI.save(r'c:\your\full\path\file.ext') to persist it to a disc.